# Tkinter Text Widget with automatic Markdown?

Tags: tkinter, text, textbox, markdown, python-3.9

Is there a Text widget in Tkinter that automatically displays the markdown of a string of text? So for example, if I insert: `**Lorem ipsum** dolor sit _amet_` to such Text widget, it automatically displays:

**Lorem ipsum** dolor sit *amet*

To achieve this, I already tried using the Text.tag_add() method to hard-code the markdown in certain parts of the text, but it didn't work somehow and it's impractical if you can do it automatically anyways. So instead I am asking if there is a type of Text widget or a function/method of the Text widget that does the work for you.

Comment: Related: [How to show markdown formatted text in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35733300/79125). But that's just for display text and not user editable text.

Answer (score 3):

There are no specific methods or attributes for automatic markdown in `tk.Text`, however it can be implemented as a binding to a function.

This code demonstrates how automatic markdown might be achieved.
Function `markdown` is called every time `Key-Return` is pressed.

```py
import tkinter as tk

M = tk.Tk()
T = tk.Text(M, undo = 1, block = 1, font = "{Courier New} 10")
T.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)

T.tag_config("mark", font = "{Courier New} 10 bold")


def markdown(event):

    S, K, E = "1.0", "", "end"
    while S > "":    
        S = T.search("**", S, stopindex = "end")
        if S:
            E = T.search("**", f"{S} + 2c", stopindex = "end")
            if E:
                E = f"{E} + 2c"
                T.tag_add("mark", S, E)
                S = K = E 
            else:
                S = ""
    # remove all **
    if K:
        A = "1.0"
        while A > "":
            A = T.search("**", A, stopindex = f"{K}")
            if A:
                T.replace(A, f"{A} + 2c", "")

R = T.bind("<Return>", markdown)
T.focus()

T.insert("1.0", """**A demonstration text for automatic markdown**

A **markdown** can be achieved by **binding** a **key** to a **function**.

This has not been fully tested **but** seems to **work** ok.
**This is a


demo of multi-line markdown**.

**This is a demo of half markdown construct

""")

M.mainloop()
```